# Maven can't find artifact for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 in Spring Repo

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Discovered that to use Spring Data ElasticSearch with ElasticSearch 5.5.0 that you need to use Spring Boot's 2.0.0.M2 milestone... However, something is wrong with my pom where maven can't seem to find the Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 milestone from the Maven repositories that I specified.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Received the following problem when doing a Maven -> Update Project in Eclipse:

```
Maven pom Loading Problem: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.0.M2 in spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release) pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For milestone versions you have to add the milestone repository with the URL `https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/`.